# Gradients do not exist for most convolution filters in subclassed model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Contain the necessary files. Add this to your "My Drive".
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1epROVNfvO10Ksy8CwJQdamSK96JZnWW9?usp=sharing
Google colab link with a minimal example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18sMqNn8IpTQLZBlInWSbX0ITd2GWDDkz?usp=sharing

This basic block 'module', if you will, is part of a larger network. It all boils down to this block, however, as this is where the convolutions are performed (in this case depthwise separable convolution). The network is seemingly able to train, however, while training (and during all the epochs) a WARNING is thrown out:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_1_upper_HG0/depthwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_1_upper_HG0/pointwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_2_upper_HG0/depthwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_2_upper_HG0/pointwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BN_1_upper_HG0/gamma:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BN_1_upper_HG0/beta:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BN_12_upper_HG0/gamma:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BN_12_upper_HG0/beta:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_1_upper_HG1/depthwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_1_upper_HG1/pointwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_2_upper_HG1/depthwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_2_upper_HG1/pointwise_kernel:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BN_1_upper_HG1/gamma:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BN_1_upper_HG1/beta:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BN_12_upper_HG1/gamma:0', 'hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BN_12_upper_HG1/beta:0', 'batch_normalization/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization/beta:0', 'batch_normalization_1/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_1/beta:0', 'batch_normalization_2/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_2/beta:0', 'batch_normalization_3/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_3/beta:0'] when minimizing the loss.
```

It all boils down to this basic block subclassed model / layer, specifically the separable convolution layers. I have no idea why it is complaining. The layer/model is called upon from other subclassed models higher up in the hierarchy
As I said,  the layer/model is called upon from other subclassed models higher up in the hierarchy. There exist many instances of this subclassed model/ layer. It is intialized similar to this:

`self.upper = BasicBlock(ncIn, ncIn, batchNorm_type=1, name=f'upper_{name}')`. in the init method of a subclassed model.

And called upon similar to this :

`out_upper = self.upper([feat])` in the call method of a subclassed model

I can't see why this would cause issues. If you have any ideas, please feel free to suggest them.

The following is a minimal example showing the issue. This is called `minima_example.py` and contains the full network structure

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
import sys

#https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/docs/tutorials/layers_normalizations.ipynb
class LightingNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, ncIn, ncOut, ncMiddle, dynamic=True, name=None):
        super(LightingNet, self).__init__(dynamic=True)
        self.ncIn = ncIn
        self.ncOut = ncOut
        self.ncMiddle = ncMiddle

        self.FC1 = SeparableConv2D(self.ncMiddle, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1), use_bias=False, name=f'FC1_Lighting_{name}')
        self.relu1 = PReLU()
        self.FC2 = SeparableConv2D(self.ncOut, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1), use_bias=False, name=f'FC2_Lighting_{name}')

    
    def call(self, inputs):
        feat = inputs[0]
        L_t= inputs[1]
        count= inputs[2]
        skip_count = inputs[3]
        x = feat[:,:,:,0:self.ncIn] 
        _, row, col, _ = x.shape
        f = tf.math.reduce_mean(x, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True )
        L_hat = self.relu1(self.FC1(f))
        L_hat = self.FC2(L_hat)

        return L_hat


class BasicBlock(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, ncIn, ncOut, batchNorm_type=0, strides=(1,1), downSample=None, dynamic=True, name=None):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__(dynamic=True)
        self.ncIn = ncIn
        self.ncOut = ncOut
        self.conv_1 = SeparableConv2D(ncOut, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", use_bias=False, name=f'BB_conv_1_{name}')
        self.conv_2 = SeparableConv2D(ncOut, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", use_bias=False, name=f'BB_conv_2_{name}') #these are the same. No idea why they decided to do a separate function for i
        if batchNorm_type == 0:
            self.bn = BatchNormalization(name=f'BN_0_{name}')
        else:
            self.bn = BatchNormalization(name=f'BN_0_{name}')
    def call(self, inputs):
            x = inputs[0]
            #print(x.shape)
            out = self.conv_1(x)
            out = self.bn(out)
            out = Activation('relu')(out) 
            out = self.conv_2(out)
            out = self.bn(out) 
            
            out = Activation('relu')(out)
            return out


class HourglassBlock(tf.keras.Model): #should it be something akin to that of NN.module but for Keras. Do they work the same?
    def __init__(self, ncIn, ncOut, next, skipLayer=True, dynamic=True, name=None):
        super(HourglassBlock, self).__init__(dynamic=True)
        self.skipLayer = True
        self.upper = BasicBlock(ncIn, ncIn, batchNorm_type=1, name=f'upper_{name}') 

        #Need a better name scheme for the layers, low1,2 are TERRIBLE names.
        self.downSample = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), name=f'downSample_{name}')
        self.low1 = BasicBlock(ncIn, ncOut, name=f'lower_{name}')
        self.next = next  #aka middle
    
    #not sure if these require output_shapes too
    def call(self, inputs):
        feat = inputs[0]
        L_t= inputs[1]
        count = inputs[2]
        skip_count= inputs[3]
        out_upper = self.upper([feat])   
        out_lower = self.downSample(feat)  
        out_lower = self.low1([out_lower])
        L_hat = self.next([out_lower, L_t, count + 1, skip_count])
        return [L_hat] 

class HourglassNet(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self, gray = True):
        super(HourglassNet, self).__init__(dynamic=True)

        self.nrSH_in = 27 #number of input spherical harmonics coeff.
        self.baseFilter = 16
        self.nrSH_out = 9 if gray else 27 #nr output SH
        self.ncPre = self.baseFilter #This is the amount required for the pre-convolution step

        self.ncHG3 = self.baseFilter #this is the amount of output channels for the first and last hourglass block
        self.ncHG2 = self.baseFilter * 2
        self.ncHG1 = self.baseFilter * 4
        self.ncHG0 = self.baseFilter * 8 + self.nrSH_in # Bottleneck layer. 
      
        self.pre_conv = SeparableConv2D(self.ncPre, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding="same", name="pre_conv")
        self.pre_bn = BatchNormalization(name="pre_bn")  
       

        self.light = LightingNet(self.nrSH_in, self.nrSH_out, 128, "LIGHT") 
        self.HG0 = HourglassBlock(self.ncHG1, self.ncHG0, self.light, name = "HG0") 
        self.HG1 = HourglassBlock(self.ncHG2, self.ncHG1, self.HG0, name = "HG1") 
        self.HG2 = HourglassBlock(self.ncHG3, self.ncHG2, self.HG1, name= "HG2") 
        self.HG3 = HourglassBlock(self.ncPre, self.ncHG3, self.HG2, name="HG3") 

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return [tf.TensorShape((1,1,1,9))] #Must somehow add L_hat to the dimensions

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        L_t= inputs[1]
        skip_count= 0
        feat = self.pre_conv(x)
        feat = self.pre_bn(feat)
        feat = Activation("relu")(feat)
        L_hat = self.HG3([feat, L_t, 0, skip_count])
        return [L_hat]
```

The following is the training code:

```
import os
import sys
#os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
#tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
#import PIL
import numpy as np 
import cv2
#from LightingNet import HourglassNet
from minima_example import HourglassNet
#import os
import pandas as pd
import functools
import re
from itertools import chain

class LightingNet:

    def __init__(self, checkpoint_file = None):
        self.generator_model = None
        self.gan_model = self.create_generator()
        self.df_train = pd.read_csv("train.lst", sep=" ")
        self.df_valid = pd.read_csv("val.lst", sep=" ")
        self.const_path = ""
        self.train_list_ptr = 0
    
    def create_generator(self):
        self.generator_model = HourglassNet() 
        in_src = Input(shape=(512,512,1))
        in_L_t = Input(shape=(1,1,9))
        in_L_gt = Input(shape=(1,1,9))
        L_hat  = self.generator_model([in_src, in_L_t])
        self.generator_model.build([(1,512,512,1), (1,1,1,9)])
        gan_model = Model([in_src, in_L_t, in_L_gt], [])
        opt = Adam()
        loss = tf.norm(tf.math.subtract(in_L_gt, L_hat), ord=2) 
        gan_model.add_loss(loss)
        gan_model.compile(optimizer=opt)
        return gan_model

    def train(self, n_epochs = 10, n_batch = 1, n_patch = 32):
        _, inp, _ = self.df_train
        epoch = 0
        while True:
            real_samples = self.generate_real_samples(n_batch, n_patch)
            [X_real_img, X_real_sh, X_gt_sh], y_real = real_samples
            X_real_img = np.concatenate(X_real_img)
            X_real_sh = np.concatenate(X_real_sh)
            X_gt_sh = np.concatenate(X_gt_sh)
            dict_loss = self.gan_model.train_on_batch([X_real_img, X_real_sh, X_gt_sh], [], return_dict= True)
            
            if self.train_list_ptr + n_batch >= self.df_train[inp].shape[0]:
               print("epoch completed")
               self.train_list_ptr = 0 #reset list ptr 
               epoch += 1 


    def generate_real_samples(self, n_samples, patch_shape):
        """
        train list looks like: 

        DIR_NAME INPUT_NAME.png TARGET_NAME.png
        DIR_NAME INPUT_NAME.png TARGET_NAME.png
        . . .
        """
        dir, inp, targ = self.df_train
        train_inp_list = self.df_train[inp].to_numpy()
        train_targ_list = self.df_train[targ].to_numpy()

        while(True):
            index = [i for i in range(self.train_list_ptr, self.train_list_ptr + n_samples)]
            assert len(index) == n_samples 
            img_samples = train_inp_list[index]
            sh_samples = train_targ_list[index] #index file from row ptr to ptr + n_samples
            self.train_list_ptr += n_samples #move ptr by n_samples 
            if all([os.path.isdir(f'{self.const_path}DPR_dataset/{re.search("(.+?)_", sample).group(1)}') for sample in img_samples ]):
                break
        
        img_list = [cv2.imread(f'{self.const_path}DPR_dataset/{re.search("(.+?)_", img).group(1)}/{img}') for img in img_samples]
        sh_gt_list = [np.loadtxt(f'{self.const_path}DPR_dataset/{re.search("(.+?)_", img).group(1)}/{re.search("(.+?)_", img).group(1)}_light_{re.search(".+?_([0-9]+)", img).group(1)}.txt') for img in img_samples]
        sh_list = [np.loadtxt(f'{self.const_path}DPR_dataset/{re.search("(.+?)_", img).group(1)}/{re.search("(.+?)_", img).group(1)}_light_{re.search(".+?_([0-9]+)", img).group(1)}.txt') for img in sh_samples]
        funcs = [(lambda x : x[0:9]), (lambda x : x * 0.7), (lambda x : np.reshape(x, (1,1,1,9))), (lambda x : x.astype(np.float32))] 
        sh_list = [functools.reduce((lambda x, y: y(x)), funcs, sh) for sh in sh_list]
        sh_gt_list = [functools.reduce((lambda x, y: y(x)), funcs, sh) for sh in sh_gt_list]
        img_list = list(map(self.inputPreprocessing, img_list))
        y = np.ones((n_samples, patch_shape, patch_shape, 1))

        return [img_list, sh_list, sh_gt_list ], y
        

    def inputPreprocessing(self, image):
        image = cv2.resize(image, (512, 512))
        LAB = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        inputL = LAB[:, :, 0]
        inputL = inputL.astype(np.float32)/255.0
        inputL = inputL[None, ..., None]
        return inputL

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("STARTING")
    g_model = LightingNet()
    g_model.train(1, 1, 32)
```

I have tested this code and it is working. The following files should reside in a folder structure `DPR_dataset/imgHQ00000/` [image: image input] with the name "imgHQ00000_00.jpg", and a txt file with:

```
1.084125496282453138e+00
-4.642676300617166185e-01
2.837846795150648915e-02
6.765292733937575687e-01
-3.594067725393816914e-01
4.790996460111427574e-02
-2.280054643781863066e-01
-8.125983081159608712e-02
2.881082012687687932e-01
```

that should be named "imgHQ00000_light_00.txt"

a file with the name "train.lst" should also exist **on the same level as the training code and the minima_example.py file** and should contain the following lines (and only these lines):

```
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
imgHQ00000 imgHQ00000_00.jpg imgHQ00000_00.jpg
```

Performing this:

```
    for i, var in enumerate(self.generator_model.trainable_variables):
        print(self.generator_model.trainable_variables[i].name  + ':                                   ' + str(tf.norm(self.generator_model.trainable_variables[i]).numpy()))
```

Gives the following:

```
pre_conv/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   0.9576778
pre_conv/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   1.464122
pre_conv/bias:0:                                   0.0009615466
pre_bn/gamma:0:                                   3.9996755
pre_bn/beta:0:                                   0.0038261134
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/lighting_net/FC1_Lighting_None/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.4065807
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/lighting_net/FC1_Lighting_None/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   6.7508173
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/lighting_net/p_re_lu/alpha:0:                                   0.0076647564
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/lighting_net/FC2_Lighting_None/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3878155
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/lighting_net/FC2_Lighting_None/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   4.050495
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_1_upper_HG0/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.4663663
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_1_upper_HG0/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   8.038067
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_2_upper_HG0/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.39229
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BB_conv_2_upper_HG0/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   8.036673
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BN_0_upper_HG0/gamma:0:                                   8.0
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block/BN_0_upper_HG0/beta:0:                                   0.0
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block_1/BB_conv_1_lower_HG0/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3681538
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block_1/BB_conv_1_lower_HG0/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   9.556786
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block_1/BB_conv_2_lower_HG0/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3960428
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block_1/BB_conv_2_lower_HG0/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   12.413813
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block_1/BN_0_lower_HG0/gamma:0:                                   12.4494915
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/hourglass_block/basic_block_1/BN_0_lower_HG0/beta:0:                                   0.010747912
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_2/BB_conv_1_upper_HG1/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3634498
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_2/BB_conv_1_upper_HG1/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   5.6760592
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_2/BB_conv_2_upper_HG1/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3929691
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_2/BB_conv_2_upper_HG1/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   5.6887717
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_2/BN_0_upper_HG1/gamma:0:                                   5.656854
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_2/BN_0_upper_HG1/beta:0:                                   0.0
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_1_lower_HG1/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3567474
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_1_lower_HG1/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   6.561019
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_2_lower_HG1/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.408531
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BB_conv_2_lower_HG1/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   8.045188
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BN_0_lower_HG1/gamma:0:                                   7.9996595
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/hourglass_block_1/basic_block_3/BN_0_lower_HG1/beta:0:                                   0.007245279
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_4/BB_conv_1_upper_HG2/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3706092
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_4/BB_conv_1_upper_HG2/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   3.8657312
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_4/BB_conv_2_upper_HG2/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.2623239
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_4/BB_conv_2_upper_HG2/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   3.9968336
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_4/BN_0_upper_HG2/gamma:0:                                   4.0
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_4/BN_0_upper_HG2/beta:0:                                   0.0
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_5/BB_conv_1_lower_HG2/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3684276
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_5/BB_conv_1_lower_HG2/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   4.6307783
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_5/BB_conv_2_lower_HG2/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3033983
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_5/BB_conv_2_lower_HG2/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   5.725787
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_5/BN_0_lower_HG2/gamma:0:                                   5.656453
hourglass_block_3/hourglass_block_2/basic_block_5/BN_0_lower_HG2/beta:0:                                   0.005336759
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_6/BB_conv_1_upper_HG3/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.4134688
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_6/BB_conv_1_upper_HG3/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   3.8999567
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_6/BB_conv_2_upper_HG3/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.4348195
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_6/BB_conv_2_upper_HG3/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   4.0438123
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_6/BN_0_upper_HG3/gamma:0:                                   4.0
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_6/BN_0_upper_HG3/beta:0:                                   0.0
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_7/BB_conv_1_lower_HG3/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.4054896
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_7/BB_conv_1_lower_HG3/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   3.9783711
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_7/BB_conv_2_lower_HG3/depthwise_kernel:0:                                   1.3978381
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_7/BB_conv_2_lower_HG3/pointwise_kernel:0:                                   3.8882372
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_7/BN_0_lower_HG3/gamma:0:                                   4.0003786
hourglass_block_3/basic_block_7/BN_0_lower_HG3/beta:0:                                   0.0038626757
```

Comment: As a first step I would suggest that you construct a _minimal_ example that produces the error. From the variable names, this model seems like a nightmare to debug with all the nested layers. At the same time the example should be _complete_, since as it is, we have no idea how the model is actually being used, so the error could be anywhere.

Comment: @xdurch0 I will get you a minimal working example hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: @xdurch0 I've added a minimal example for you. I have also tried running this example and it outputs the same warning. Thanks for taking a look at this :)

Comment: @xdurch0 added a google colab minimal example to more easily showcase the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reworking the network and putting all the layers one after the other rather than having multiple instances of a model. So everything from beginning to end is in one single subclassed model.